# Why does jquery UI not render select boxes properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a simple select box:

```
<select id="targetDept" name="targetDept" class="ui-select" onclick="clearApprovers()">
<option value="1">blah</option>
<option value="2">blah2</option>
<option value="3">blah3</option>
<option value="4">blah4</option>
</select>
```

I try to make it into a fancy jquery select box:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".ui-select").selectmenu();
    $(".ui-button").button();

});
```

Here are my includes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.theme.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

It works but it makes the select into the most ugly thing. Unfortunately, because of company computer policies, I cant upload a picture so i will try to describe it.

The dropdow itself is essentially a button and the left and right padding is 0 (ie the text is touching the border of the "button"). When I click on the dropdown, it opens a SUPER wide span, that is about 3 times the width of my actual page, creating a scroll bar along the bottom. Each option is beside a big black bullet point and clicking an option does not select it, leaving the options open and not really doing anything...

I know it's not easy to diagnose, but thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are missing the jquery-ui core css file. If you downloaded the zip file from the Jquery homepage it's in the root folder called jquery-ui.css.

The theme file only provides the colours - not the base styling needed to make it function correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you included all the css file from jquery-ui package? Because `jquery-ui.theme.css` is just a theme of `jquery-ui.css`.